# Regex match specific word and word with repeat lettres

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

in js (nodejs) i try to catch a specific word and this same word write with repeat letter ...

exemple, if i say world, i want catch this: 
world woorld wwooorld worllddd worldddd

so i can juste make a for on my world an create a dynamique regexw with something like this:

```
var w = 'world';
var regex = '';
for(var i = 0; i < w.lengh; i++){
 regex += `${w[i]}+`;
}
```

but can i do this only with one unique regex ?? ( or other original idea )

Comment: your output is unclear: some characters are repeating only 2 times, some - 3 times

Comment: What do you mean `one unique regex`. As it is now `w+o+r+l+d+` will find at _least_ all those letters and in order. As will `w+o+o+f+e+r+` It's not necessary but you could always use a regex to make `woofer` `w+o+f+e+r+`, then use that to match something. Find `(\w)\1*` replace `$1+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of constructing the regex is correct. You need however to take care that characters with a special meaning in regular expressions do not make things go wrong. So you could escape non-alphanumerical characters with a backslash:

```js
var w = "world+hello";
var regex = new RegExp('^' + w.replace(/\W/g, '\\$&+').replace(/\w/g, '$&+') + '$');
console.log(regex, regex.test('wwoooorllldd++++hhelllo'));
```

Comment: An fyi, on some engines (not sure about JS), a `\<` denotes a word boundary. I'd try to stick to `[metachars]` if possible.

Comment: Interesting, @sin. Not so in JS. Which flavour of regex is that? It looks like `[[:<:]]` in PCRE.

Comment: Not sure, but I read it somewhere https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Ok, it's gnu that uses `start of word` stuff `\<` and also boost.

Comment: This is what i'm looking

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern would match any combination of letter repeats for "world":

```
"w+o+r+l+d+"
```

The `+` denotes capturing 1 or more of the previous character.